# displaying full url path for the selected images in ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

This should be simple task but i am not been able to find the answer of it.
I am using CKEditor in my aspx pages and i want to display full URL path when user select any image there. Right now, when user select the path it shows like

```
<img alt="" src="/XXX/ckeditor/images/Desert.jpg" style="width: 960px; height: 720px; " />
```

i want to display it like

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/XXX/ckeditor/images/Desert.jpg" style="width: 960px; height: 720px; " />
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: done changes in code of imagebrowser.aspx and i am good for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one changes in code of imagebrowser.aspx since i am using the custom version of ckeditor with file upload functinality and i am good for now